# Android studio : How to change icon in task manager

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio :- I changed the app icon by changing ic_launcher.png , but in the task manager showing recent app, I still see droid . How to change that any GUI option ?

Comment: try uninstall and rerun again

Comment: Is the Task Manager of Windows?

Comment: Close from the task manager, rebuild the app, re-run the app, and it should change

Comment: re installing worked.... could have been cached earlier

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me, on a Nexus 5x API 29 (Android 10) Emulator

From Settings -> Apps & Notifications -> 'see all xx apps' find the Launcher, e.g. Pixel Launcher, Clear the Cache and Storage for that, force quit it, hit the Home button, wait for the launcher to reload, and all should be good.